# SQL Server 2008 R2 return a row even when no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some of the following data:

```
+------+--------+-----+------+
| Team | Status | Bye | Wins |
+------+--------+-----+------+
| Cle  | New    |   1 |    5 |
| Tam  | New    |   3 |    0 |
| Bal  | New    |   3 |    2 |
| Ind  | Cur    |   4 |    0 |
| LAC  | New    |   4 |    2 |
| NYG  | Cur    |   5 |    0 |
| Chi  | Cur    |   5 |    0 |
+------+--------+-----+------+
```

There are 5 bye weeks and a query may return a result without a particular bye week, say 2 in this situation. I want to return a recordset from the table but also return a row(s) with the missing number in the Bye week and everything else in that row empty (where there are no Bye's). I think I can do it with a UNION but seems like a lot of work and hoping there's an easier\more efficient way.

I've seen other posts to return an empty row but those do not include returning other valid rows along with it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited my question as there could be any missing bye week(s) not just 2.

Comment: Please, don't post your data as images - use text for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some other great answers here, but I'll share what I've done in a similar situation. Basically, I have a "defaults" table that I can UNION to and then only return any missing rows from it.

I have created the following example, based on your sample data above, that you can run in SSMS.

```
-- replicate your environment --

DECLARE @data TABLE ( [team] VARCHAR(3), [status] VARCHAR(3), [bye] INT, [wins] INT );
INSERT INTO @data ( [team], [status], [bye], [wins] )
VALUES
  ( 'Cle', 'New', 1, 5 )
, ( 'Tam', 'New', 3, 0 )
, ( 'Bal', 'New', 3, 2 )
, ( 'Ind', 'Cur', 4, 0 )
, ( 'LAC', 'New', 4, 2 )
, ( 'NYG', 'Cur', 5, 0 )
, ( 'Chi', 'Cur', 5, 0 );

-- declare a "defaults" table variable --

DECLARE @defaults TABLE ( [team] VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '--', [status] VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT '--', [bye] INT, [wins] INT );

-- insert default data based on what I surmised from your question --

INSERT INTO @defaults ( [bye], [wins] ) VALUES ( 1, 0 ), ( 2, 0 ), ( 3, 0 ), ( 4, 0 ), ( 5, 0 );

-- select data using the "defaults" table to "fill in the wholes" --

SELECT [team], [status], [bye], [wins] FROM @data
UNION
SELECT [team], [status], [bye], [wins] FROM @defaults
WHERE [bye] NOT IN ( SELECT [bye] FROM @data )
ORDER BY
    [bye], [team];
```

Which returns

```
+------+--------+-----+------+
| team | status | bye | wins |
+------+--------+-----+------+
| Cle  | New    |   1 |    5 |
| --   | --     |   2 |    0 |
| Bal  | New    |   3 |    2 |
| Tam  | New    |   3 |    0 |
| Ind  | Cur    |   4 |    0 |
| LAC  | New    |   4 |    2 |
| Chi  | Cur    |   5 |    0 |
| NYG  | Cur    |   5 |    0 |
+------+--------+-----+------+
```

Another alternative would be to expand upon @Yogesh's use of `FROM ( VALUES )`:

```
SELECT [team], [status], [bye], [wins] FROM @data
UNION
SELECT [team], [status], [bye], [wins] 
FROM ( 
    VALUES ( '--', '--', 1, 0 ), ( '--', '--', 2, 0 ), ( '--', '--', 3, 0 ), ( '--', '--', 4, 0 ), ( '--', '--', 5, 0 )
 ) AS MyTable( [team], [status], [bye], [wins] )
WHERE [bye] NOT IN ( SELECT [bye] FROM @data )
ORDER BY
    [bye], [team];
```

Which returns the same results as above without the need/overhead of a table variable.

Comment: Great! I didn't know it would be so complicated (for me anyway) and thanks for expanding on @Yogesh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values` construct with `join` :

```
select t.bye, tt.*
from ( values (2) 
     ) t (bye) left join
     table tt
     on t.bye = tt.bye;
```

EDIT : After review the question again you seem want `union` with `not exists` :

```
select t.team, t.status, t.bye, t.wins
from table t
where bye = 2
union all
select t.team, t.status, t.bye, t.wins
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where bye = 2);
```

EDIT : use recursive `cte` to find missing `bye`s :

```
with t as (
     select min(bye) mn_bye, max(bye) mx_bye
     from table
     union all
     select mn_bye + 1, mx_bye
     from t
     where mn_bye < mx_bye
)

select tt.*, coalesce(cast(t.mn_bye as varchar(255)), 'missing') 
from t left join
     table tt
     on tt.bye = t.mn_bye;
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `Bye`s with 4 on purpose so that the result could be better seen.

```
declare @t table
(
    Team     char(3) null,
    [Status] char(3) null,
    Bye      tinyint null,
    Wins     tinyint null
);

insert into @t values
('Cle', 'New', 1, 5),
('Tam', 'New', 3, 0),
('Bal', 'New', 3, 2),
--('Ind', 'Cur', 4, 0),
--('LAC', 'New', 4, 2),
('NYG', 'Cur', 5, 0),
('Chi', 'Cur', 5, 0);

with info as
(
    select x.*, x.next_row_bye - Bye diff
    from
    (
        select *,
               LEAD(Bye) OVER (ORDER BY Bye) next_row_bye,
               Bye + 1 next_bye
        from @t
    ) x
)
select null Team, null [Status], next_bye Bye, 0 Wins
from info
where diff > 0
union
select *
from @t
order by Bye;
```

#### RESULT:

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Thanks JohnyL but I'm using 2008 which doesn't recognize LEAD. I have edited my question to include 2008.